# Selection by Event Type (or Event parameter type) possible with Reactor and Spring?

Tags: spring, events, consumer, reactor

I want to use Reactor something like that:

```
reactor.notify(new CreatedEvent<A>(a));
reactor.notify(new CreatedEvent<B>(b));
```

Where my event is simply:

```
public class CreatedEvent<E> extends Event<E> {
    public CreatedEvent(E data) {
        super(data);
    }
}
```

And then consume those events like that:

```
reactor.on(new Consumer<CreatedEvent<A>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(CreatedEvent<A> t) {
        /* do something with a */
    }
});

reactor.on(new Consumer<CreatedEvent<B>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(CreatedEvent<B> t) {
        /* do something with b */
    }
});
```

But I receive both events with both consumers.

If I use selectors it works, i.e.:

```
reactor.notify("created.a", Event.wrap(a));

reactor.on(Selectors.$("created.a"), new Consumer<Event<A>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Event<A> t) {
        /* do something with a */
    }
});
```

But using selectors I would have to write and maintain very much String.

Is it all about using selectors? Or can I somehow "select by parameterized class type"?

Answer (score 3):

> But I receive both events with both consumers.

Right. Because you send both events to the same `reactor` just to `defaultKey`.
And subscribe both `consumers` to the `defaultSelector`.
In this case it doesn't have value which types of `Event` you use: they all will be dispatched by default `Selector` strategy.

I think you need to use `ClassSelector`:

```
reactor.notify(a);
reactor.notify(b);

reactor.on(Selectors.T(A.class), new Consumer<Event<A>>() {});
reactor.on(Selectors.T(B.class), new Consumer<Event<B>>() {});
```

Of course, you have to type `Selectors.T` for each `class-consumer`, but it is more simpler then `ObjectSelector` and custom `Event`.

UPDATE

How to inject a `custom consumer filter`:

```
Reactors.reactor()
            .eventFilter(new GenericResolverFilter())
            .get()
```

And it's up to you how to resolve a generic argument from `consumerKey` Object and each `Consumer` from `List<T> items`. Anyway you should think here about some caching to allow to Reactor continue to be `reactive`.

Comment: Thank you. But that's only half the way... I need something like a "ParameterizedClassSelector", so I can write `reactor.on(Selectors.T(Created<A>.class), ...)` or `reactor.on(Selectors.T(Deleted<B>.class), ...)`, which of course is no valid Java, but I hope you understand what I am looking for? (Is this what I'm looking for: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/issues/207 ? )

Comment: Actually, you always can write your own `Selector` implementation. From other side, as your enclosing classes are diferent, you can implement your own `Filter` with generic resolution and inject it to `ConsumerFilteringEventRouter` and continue to use `ClassSelector` for enclosing classes.

Comment: As far as I understand, you say that I have the following choices: **1.** Use default Selector with `r.on(Selectors.T(Created.class), new Consumer<Event<A>>() {})` with custom filter, or **2.** Write a custom Selector and use `r.on(CustomSelector(Created.class, A.class), new Consumer<Event<A>>() {})`. Right? The **1.** Approach looks far more elegant to me, but I don't know how to do it. Could you provide a link are append a small example code for how to inject a custom filter into `ConsumerFilterEventRouter`?

Comment: I've updated my answer with sample about injection of custom `Filter`

Comment: Thank you. This new Filter will override the old Filter, right? For caching I'd have a look at the given filters that are provided.

Comment: Not old, but default one: https://github.com/reactor/reactor/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/Reactor.java#L61. No, no one `Filter` implementation has caching. I mean you should get generics from both parts: `selectorKey` and consumer and store that introspaction info for future use. Suppose your Consumer may take care of it by constructor: `class MyConsumer<A> implements Consumer<Event<A>> {private Class<A> aClass;}`